# Raspberry Pi (Raspbian stretch) 上の Docker で Mosquitto が直ぐ Exited してしまう。

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ssl

Raspberry Pi (Raspbian stretch) 上で稼働する Docker で で Mosquitto が直ぐ Exited してしまう。

何度もトライ＆エラーをしながら探ってきましたが何をすればいいか思いつきません。
なぜ Docker run で Exited となるのかがわかりません。
原因を探るための方法や場所、ファイルなど、何かのヒントでもよろしいのでご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**【実現したいこと】**
Raspberry Pi 上の Docker で Mosquitto Brokerを TLS で稼働させたい。

**【今まで実行したこと】**
**Docker インストール**
Raspberry Pi 3 B+ に 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-lite をインストール。
Docker を公式を参考にインストール。
Docker で Hallo World 実行確認済。

**Docker HUB の eclipse-mosquitto で実験**
Docker HUB にあった
[eclipse-mosquitto](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) を手順通り進めると
System error: exec format error が出た。

**GitHub の Mosibi/mosquitto で実験**
TLS を行いたかったので GitHub にあった [Mosibi/mosquitto](https://github.com/Mosibi/mosquitto) を手順通りに進めると
System error: exec format error が出た。

ここで FROM で指定する OS を Raspbian にしないといけないことに気付く。

**Docker HUB の [schachr/raspbian-stretch](https://hub.docker.com/r/schachr/raspbian-stretch/) で実験**
docker pull schachr/raspbian-stretch して
手順通り進めると無事コンテナの中のbashが起動する。
その後 Hallo World の DockerFile を他から引用して実行すると無事表示。

**[Mosibi/mosquitto](https://github.com/Mosibi/mosquitto) の FROM を変更して実験**

```
FROM schachr/raspbian-stretch:latest
```

と変更して docker run 実行

```
docker run -d --net=host \
    -e "FQDN=mqtt.example.com" \
    -e "EMAIL=me@example.com" \
    -e "DOMAIN=example.com" \
    -e "IPLIST=172.16.16.16 192.168.1.254" \
    -e "HOSTLIST=somehost.example.com docker.example.com" \
    -v /home/admin/mosquitto/conf.d:/etc/mosquitto/conf.d:z \
    -t mosibi/mosquitto
```

すると

```
System error: exec format error
```

ここからエラー探しやDockerFileの変更などをトライ&エラーで実行して現在に至る(長かった orz けど朧気ながら Docker の雰囲気がわかりました)
ここからが本題です。

**【改変 DockerFile で実行したこと】**
DockerFile

```
FROM schachr/raspbian-stretch:latest

MAINTAINER admin <admind@example.com>

ENV LC_ALL="C" \
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8" \
    TZ="Asia/Tokyo"


WORKDIR /tmp

# Configure no init scripts to run on package updates.
ADD files/policy-rc.d /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
RUN chmod 755 /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d                     && \
: dash を bash に変更                                   && \
    ln -f /bin/bash /bin/sh                             && \
    apt update                                          && \
    apt install -y  rename openssl                         \
                    mosquitto mosquitto-clients         && \
: mosquitto フォルダを空にする                            && \
    rm -rf /etc/mosquitto                               && \
    mkdir /etc/mosquitto

# COPY files
COPY volume /etc/mosquitto/
COPY files/generate-CA.sh /usr/local/bin/generate-CA.sh
COPY files/init /init
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/generate-CA.sh     && \
    chmod 755 /init

# generate-CA.sh 実行時のディレクトリ
WORKDIR /etc/mosquitto/.ca

# MQTT ports
#EXPOSE 1883
EXPOSE 8883
EXPOSE 9001

CMD [ "/init" ]
```

Raspberry Pi の tree

```
$HOME/SmartHome/
├─ README.md
└─ docker
   └── mosquitto
       ├── Dockerfile
       ├── files
       │   ├── generate-CA.sh
       │   ├── init
       │   └── policy-rc.d
       └── volume
           ├── ca_certificates
           │   └── mqtt_ca.crt
           ├── certs
           │   ├── mqtt_srv.crt
           │   └── mqtt_srv.key
           ├── conf.d
           │   ├── mosquitto.conf
           │   └── websockets.conf
           ├── mosquitto.conf
           ├── mosquitto.conf.example
           └── password.txt
```

実行手順
Docker run したが直ぐに Exited となる。

```
$ cd SmartHome/docker/mosquitto
$ docker build -t admin/mosquitto .
$ docker run -it -d --name mosquitto --net=host \
    -e "FQDN=pi.example.us" \
    -e "EMAIL=me@example.com" \
    -e "DOMAIN=example.com" \
    -e "IPLIST=192.168.0.220 172.20.10.220" \
    -e "HOSTLIST=pi pi.local pi.example.us 192.168.0.220 172.20.10.220" \
    -v /home/admin/SmartHome/docker/mosquitto/volume:/etc/mosquitto \
    -t admin/mosquitto
$ docker ps -a
・・・ Exited (1) 10 seconds ago
```

Docker logs を見ると /init コマンドは実行されていることが分かった。

```
$ docker logs mosquitto
/etc/mosquitto/.ca
Generating a RSA private key
...............+++++
................................................+++++
writing new private key to './ca.key'
-----
Created CA certificate in ./ca.crt
subject=
    commonName                = MQTT Broker example.com
    organizationName          = example.com
    emailAddress              = me@example.com
Warning: the CA key is not encrypted; store it safely!
--- Creating server key and signing request
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..+++++
.....................................................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
--- Creating and signing server certificate
Signature ok
subject=CN = pi.example.us, O = example.com, emailAddress = me@example.com
Getting CA Private Key
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1281 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_ca.crt
-r-------- 1 root root 1704 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_ca.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_ca.srl
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1891 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_srv.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  968 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_srv.csr
-r-------- 1 root root 1679 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_srv.key
/etc/mosquitto/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 28 16:07 .ca
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 28 16:07 ca_certificates
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 28 16:07 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 1000  4096 Jan 28 16:00 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   750 Jan 28 16:00 mosquitto.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 33112 Jan 28 16:00 mosquitto.conf.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   115 Jan 28 16:00 password.txt
/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1281 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_ca.crt
/etc/mosquitto/certs/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1891 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_srv.crt
-r-------- 1 root root 1679 Jan 28 16:07 mqtt_srv.key
/etc/mosquitto/password.txt
admin:$6$uXNbKcSuDpNZYcmHivYC1fg3neSmmsdLxlI5A==
```

マウントしたボリュームを見るとCA証明書類が作成されている。

```
$ ls -A SmartHome/docker/mosquitto/volume/.ca
.gitkeep     mqtt_ca.key  mqtt_srv.crt  mqtt_srv.key
mqtt_ca.crt  mqtt_ca.srl  mqtt_srv.csr
```

コンテナをコミットして中に入る準備をする。

```
$ docker commit mosquitto debug
$ docker run --rm -it debug /bin/bash
```

**ここから debug イメージの中**
debug イメージの中を確認するとCA証明書類はない（マウントのコマンドをしてないから多分）

```
$ pwd
/etc/mosquitto/.ca
$ ls -A
.gitkeep
```

ここで /init コマンドを実行してみる。

```
$ /init
WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory swappiness capabilities, memory swappiness discarded.
root@aba7a43aaeab:/etc/mosquitto/.ca# /init
/etc/mosquitto/.ca
Generating a RSA private key
..............................................................................+++++
.................................................................................................................+++++
writing new private key to './ca.key'
-----
Created CA certificate in ./ca.crt
subject=
    commonName                = MQTT Broker example.com
    organizationName          = example.com
    emailAddress              = me@example.com
Warning: the CA key is not encrypted; store it safely!
--- Creating server key and signing request
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
.................+++++
......+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
--- Creating and signing server certificate
Signature ok
subject=CN = pi.example.us, O = example.com, emailAddress = me@example.com
Getting CA Private Key
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1281 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_ca.crt
-r-------- 1 root root 1708 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_ca.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   17 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_ca.srl
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1883 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_srv.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  968 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_srv.csr
-r-------- 1 root root 1675 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_srv.key
/etc/mosquitto/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jan 28 16:40 .ca
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jan 28 16:40 ca_certificates
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jan 28 16:40 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 28 16:10 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root   750 Jan 28 16:00 mosquitto.conf
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root 33112 Jan 28 16:00 mosquitto.conf.example
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root   115 Jan 28 16:00 password.txt
/etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1281 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_ca.crt
/etc/mosquitto/certs/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 9 root root   21 Jan 28 16:00 .gitkeep
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 1883 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_srv.crt
-r-------- 1 root root 1675 Jan 28 16:40 mqtt_srv.key
/etc/mosquitto/password.txt
admin:$6$uXNKcSuDpNZYWO9I$6FmqWeO==
▮
```

プロンプトが点滅している状態がずっと続いてる。Ctr-P,Ctr-Qで戻れない。

ここで違う端末のSSHで同じアカウントにログインして確認する。

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
aba7a43aaeab        debug               "/bin/bash"         13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       8883/tcp, 9001/tcp   tender_poincare
```

Exited にならずに Up になっている。

以上が実行したことです。

なぜ最初の Docker run で Exited となるのかがわかりません。
何かのヒントでもよろしいのでご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

【環境】
Raspberry Pi 3 B+
2018-11-13-Raspbian-Stretch-Lite
Doccker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
Server:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
技量:初心者

```
/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf はオリジナルのままです。

$ cat /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf
# 1883 はlocalhost 以外からは受け付けない
listener 1883 localhost
# TSL/SSL ポート
listener 8883

# 認証にパスワードファイルが必要になる
#allow_anonymous false

# パスワードファイル
password_file /etc/mosquitto/password.txt

# CA証明書
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mqtt_ca.crt

# サーバー証明書
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.crt

# サーバーキー
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.key


$ cat /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/websockets.conf
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

/init です

```
#!/bin/bash

if  [[ "new" = "$1" ]] ||
    [[ ! -f /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/mqtt_ca.crt ]] ||
    [[ ! -f /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.key ]] ||
    [[ ! -f /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.crt ]]; then

    cd /etc/mosquitto/.ca
    pwd
    rm -rf *
    # CA証明書生成
    /usr/local/bin/generate-CA.sh ${FQDN}
    # ca.xxx ファイルをリネーム
    /usr/bin/rename s/ca./mqtt_ca./ *
    # pi.example.us.xxx ファイルをリネーム
    /usr/bin/rename s/${FQDN}/mqtt_srv/ *
    ls -Al
    # mosquitto に配置
    cp -rf mqtt_ca.crt /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
    cp -rf mqtt_srv.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs/
    cp -rf mqtt_srv.key /etc/mosquitto/certs/
    echo /etc/mosquitto/
    ls -Al /etc/mosquitto/
    echo /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
    ls -Al /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
    echo /etc/mosquitto/certs/
    ls -Al /etc/mosquitto/certs/
    echo /etc/mosquitto/password.txt
    cat /etc/mosquitto/password.txt
fi

/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。   
様々なOSイメージを取り換えながら実行してようやく実行できる環境に出会えました。   
FROM arm32v7/buildpack-deps:stretch